# Azure react sample gives "invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid"

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, adal, msal

I'm looking at the steps mentioned in the sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial/ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial-1-call-api-react/). Using my own tenant (`11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111`), I successfully configured everything until this step: `Explore the sample`.
Now when I launch applications and try to login with my gmail account (AD domain `%MY_GMAIL_NAME%gmail.onmicrosoft.com`), I see the following error (after I've typed my gmail account and clicked proceed):

> We're unable to complete your request

> invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for this client application.

Web API configuration (address `https://localhost:44351`):

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://%MY_GMAIL_NAME%gmail.ciamlogin.com/",
  "TenantId": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
  "ClientId": "...WEB_API_APP_REGISTRATION_GUID....",
  "Scopes": {
    "Read": [ "ToDoList.Read", "ToDoList.ReadWrite" ],
    "Write": [ "ToDoList.ReadWrite" ]
  },
  "AppPermissions": {
    "Read": [ "ToDoList.Read.All", "ToDoList.ReadWrite.All" ],
    "Write": [ "ToDoList.ReadWrite.All" ]
  }
},
```

Web app config (address `http://localhost:3000`):

```
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: '...WEB_APP_APP_REGISTRATION_GUID....', // This is the ONLY mandatory field that you need to supply.
        authority: 'https://%MY_GMAIL_NAME%gmail.ciamlogin.com/', 
        redirectUri: '/', // You must register this URI on Azure Portal/App Registration. Defaults to window.location.origin
        postLogoutRedirectUri: '/', // Indicates the page to navigate after logout.
    },
   ...
};

export const protectedResources = {
    toDoListAPI: {
        endpoint: 'https://localhost:44351/api/todolist',
        scopes: {
            read: ['api://...WEB_API_APP_REGISTRATION_GUID..../ToDoList.Read'],
            write: ['api://...WEB_API_APP_REGISTRATION_GUID..../ToDoList.ReadWrite'],
        },
    },
};
```

In app registration for "ciam-msal-react-spa" and accordingly to the initially mentioned guide, in `Authentication` tab, I've specified `Single-page application` platform with these 2 redirect uris:

```
1. http://localhost:3000
2. http://localhost:3000/redirect
```

I've specified the rest of the steps too, so not sure where I've done mistake.

**UPDATE1**: I saw similar but not exactly the same issue [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial/issues/70). The solution there is to use `authority url` like this `https://login.microsoftonline.com/` (instead `https://%MY_GMAIL_NAME%gmail.ciamlogin.com/`). When I did this, I started to see error immediately when I click `SignIn` on the index page (so I even don't see a window where I can type my email).

```
@azure/msal-browser@2.38.3 : Info - Emitting event: msal:loginFailure authConfig.js:40
ClientAuthError: endpoints_resolution_error: Error: could not resolve endpoints. Please check network and try again. Detail: ClientAuthError: openid_config_error: Could not retrieve endpoints. Check your authority and verify the .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint returns the required endpoints. Attempted to retrieve endpoints from: https://login.microsoftonline.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
    AuthError AuthError.ts:49
    ClientAuthError ClientAuthError.ts:222
    ..
```

**UPDATE2**: as suggested, please see the full list of steps I took here:

```
===========API:=================
1. Regiser app: "ciam-msal-dotnet-api" (`...WEB_API_APP_REGISTRATION_GUID....`)
2. In Expose API:
2.1. Add Scope: ToDoList.Read/ReadWrite
3.In Manifest: 
3.1. "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
4.In App Roles:
4.1. Add App role: ToDoList.(Read|ReadWrite).All/  (Allowed member types => applications)
5. In Token configuration:
5.1. Add optional claim: "idtyp"

Fill appsettings.json:

    "AzureAd": {
      "Instance": "https://%MY_GMAIL_NAME%gmail.ciamlogin.com/",
      "TenantId": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
      "ClientId": "...WEB_API_APP_REGISTRATION_GUID....",
      "Scopes": {
        "Read": [ "ToDoList.Read", "ToDoList.ReadWrite" ],
        "Write": [ "ToDoList.ReadWrite" ]
      },
      "AppPermissions": {
        "Read": [ "ToDoList.Read.All", "ToDoList.ReadWrite.All" ],
        "Write": [ "ToDoList.ReadWrite.All" ]
      }
    },
===========UI:==================
1. Regiser app: "ciam-msal-react-spa" (`...WEB_APP_APP_REGISTRATION_GUID....`)
2. In Authentication:
2.1. Add platform => Single-page application => set redirect urls: [http://localhost:3000, http://localhost:3000/redirect]
3. In API permissions:
3.1. API permission => Add permission =>Microsoft Graph => delegated permissions => openId permissions (openid, offline_access)
3.2. API permission => Add permission (My APIs) => Add registed API => Delegated permission => ToDoList.Read/ReadWrite
3.3. API permission => Grant admin consent for defaul directory

Fill authConfig.js:

    export const msalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: '...WEB_APP_APP_REGISTRATION_GUID....', // This is the ONLY mandatory field that you need to supply.
            authority: 'https://%MY_GMAIL_NAME%gmail.ciamlogin.com/', 
            redirectUri: '/', // You must register this URI on Azure Portal/App Registration. Defaults to window.location.origin
            postLogoutRedirectUri: '/', // Indicates the page to navigate after logout.
        },
       ...
    };

    export const protectedResources = {
        toDoListAPI: {
            endpoint: 'https://localhost:44351/api/todolist',
            scopes: {
                read: ['api://...WEB_API_APP_REGISTRATION_GUID..../ToDoList.Read'],
                write: ['api://...WEB_API_APP_REGISTRATION_GUID..../ToDoList.ReadWrite'],
            },
        },
    };
```

**UPDATE3:**
Thanks @Gaurav Mantri, if I use the following authority link `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>`, it looks like the issue is gone. However why it's recommended with `ciamlogin` suffix in a first place? See [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial/blob/main/2-Authorization/1-call-api-react/API/ToDoListAPI/appsettings.json#L3).

**UPDATE4:**
As it was pointed by @Gaurav Mantri, there is a github [page](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/configuration.md) where some of related details can be found. Diving into the links inside shown me the following paragraph [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-common/docs/authority.md#ciam):

> The CIAM authority format is still in the process of standardization. It is determined to be split from AAD and currently supported in the below formats:
>
> - https://tenantName.ciamlogin.com/tenant
> - https://tenantName.ciamlogin.com

> Where tenant would mean:
>
> - tenantName.microsoft.com
> - GUID (tenantId)
> - a verified domain for the tenant

In additional to the previous attempts I did with `https://tenantName.ciamlogin.com`, I've just tried `https://tenantName.ciamlogin.com/<tenant>` using guid tenant Id instead `<tenant>`. It has given the same error as before.

Comment: Please edit to include what you're trying to do - nobody should need to visit an external site to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `https://login.microsoftonline.com/` is not a valid authority URL.

Here's what the documentation says about the authority URL:

> The authority is a URL that indicates a directory that MSAL can
> request tokens from.

Please see the documentation here for valid values of Authority URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-client-application-configuration#authority.

Comment: this one `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/` works for me. Thanks! Do you know why the mentioned examples suggest using `https://%MY_GMAIL_NAME%gmail.ciamlogin.com/`?

Comment: fyi initial value in the example was `"Instance": "https://Enter_the_Tenant_Subdomain_Here.ciamlogin.com/"

Comment: Can you provide a direct link for this: Do you know why the mentioned examples suggest using https://%MY_GMAIL_NAME%gmail.ciamlogin.com/? Thanks.

Comment: yes, in the initial link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial/ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial-1-call-api-react/, search for the following text: `Configure the service app (ciam-msal-dotnet-api) to use your app registration` (sorry no direct link allowed).

Then see #4:

Comment: "Find the placeholder Enter_the_Tenant_Subdomain_Here and replace it with the Directory (tenant) subdomain. For instance, if your tenant primary domain is contoso.onmicrosoft.com, use contoso. If you don't have your tenant domain name, learn how to read your tenant details."

Comment: where as I mentioned above, the place holder `Enter_the_Tenant_Subdomain_Here` is placed in this line (with suffix `ciamlogin.com`): `Enter_the_Tenant_Subdomain_Here.ciamlogin.com`. See here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial/blob/main/2-Authorization/1-call-api-react/API/ToDoListAPI/appsettings.json#L3

Comment: and subdomain in my AD is `%MY_GMAIL_NAME%gmail`, like `namelastnamegmail.onmicrosoft.com`

Comment: `"Instance": "https://Enter_the_Tenant_Subdomain_Here.ciamlogin.com/"` - This is for authorizing your front-end app with your API. Here, the token is retrieved for your API. HTH.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get it, the same line is placed in web app: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial/blob/main/2-Authorization/1-call-api-react/SPA/src/authConfig.js#L16

Comment: Please see the explanation here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/configuration.md. HTH.

Comment: at first glance, I see nothing related to customer identity and access management (CIAM), but I will double check it tomorrow

Comment: it looks like it's possible to have authority with CIAM: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-common/docs/authority.md#ciam. But neither the old way I used ('https://tenantName.ciamlogin.com') nor the suggested (https://tenantName.ciamlogin.com/tenantId) work for me. Both give the initial exception