# Incorrect Redirect URI in microsoft login

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-entra-id

I am trying to create an ASP.NET Core Web API which will use Microsoft login. I want the code to fetch the token and later I will use that token, that is a different story, as of now I am able to login but just after login, I get this error

> We're unable to complete your request
> Invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for this client application.

In the Azure portal, I have registered a web application and mentioned redirect URI as `http://localhost:5091/testlogin` and below is the code

```
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("login")]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(TestLogin), "Account", null, Request.Scheme);
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl };

        return Challenge(properties, "Microsoft");
    }

    [HttpGet("testlogin")]
    public IActionResult TestLogin()
    {
        foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{claim.Type}: {claim.Value}");
        }

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userEmail = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
            var authenticationToken = User.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier")?.Value;
            return Ok(new
                      {
                          Email = userEmail,
                          Token = authenticationToken
                      });
        }
        else
        {
            return Unauthorized("User is not authenticated.");
        }
    }

    [HttpPost("logout")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        return Ok("Logged out successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,@Code Noob,Here's an issue related :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77896215/azure-react-sample-gives-invalid-request-the-provided-value-for-the-input-para,you could check the configuration in appsettings.json follow this issue